# How can extract frames from a gif without any file manipulation?

Tags: node.js

What I want to do is to extract the frames from a gif without using file manipulation at all.

To start, I get a gif using this:

```js
const request = require('request');
const sharp = require('sharp');

const url = 'https://media.tenor.com/F4-i1leMvrUAAAAd/dunk-slam-dunk.gif';
request.get({ url, encoding: null }, async function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const gif = Buffer.from(body, 'base64')
        const sharpedGif = await sharp(gif)
    }
});
```

I tried getting a frame from the gif by using:

```js
var frame = 1
const request = require('request');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true})

const url = 'https://media.tenor.com/F4-i1leMvrUAAAAd/dunk-slam-dunk.gif';
request.get({ url, encoding: null }, async function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(
        gm(Buffer.from(body, 'base64'))
        .selectFrame(frame)
        .sourceBuffer
        )
    }
});
```

But, It always returns the first frame of the gif, not the frame i asked for.

I need help on how I can fix this.

Comment: In the docu I never find `selectFrame` but instead the notation `gm('/path/to/animated.gif[0]')` where the `[0]` is the number for the frame. This is independent from using gm or im, at least after short verification of the docus.

Comment: @David How can I do that without a path to a file, but, instead, with the buffer of a gif?

Comment: Just try `gm(Buffer.from(body, 'base64')[frame])` perhaps?

Comment: @David `gm(Buffer.from(body, 'base64')+"['"+frame+"']")` worked.

Comment: great, nice that you could solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `gif-frames` instead of `sharp`:

```js
var gifFrames = require('gif-frames');
var fs = require('fs');
 
gifFrames({ url: 'image.gif', frames: 0 }).then(function (frameData) {
  frameData[0].getImage().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('firstframe.jpg'));
});
```

Comment: i specifically didn't want to use file manipulation, i've already use this method before.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

To present an answer of the solution from the comments:

> In the docu I never find selectFrame but instead the notation gm('/path/to/animated.gif[0]') where the [0] is the number for the frame. This is independent from using gm or im, at least after short verification of the docus.

For the slightly different situation that a buffer is used, this solution is working:

```
gm(Buffer.from(body, 'base64')+"['"+frame+"']")
```

Comment: @Load Lua If you want to write and upvote your own answer, I can delete mine too. You'd get a few points and the users have one answer visible marked as solved.

Comment: Turns out it doesn't work after frame 30+, no matter what GIF. I'll go looking for another method to fix this.

Comment: You get the same problem if you use `const gm = require('gm')` only?